# Единство несогласованного определения. Стилистическая ошибка

Tags: грамотная-речь, однородные-члены, определения, стилистическая-ошибка

1. *Для нас важно **количество** и **активность** участников.*
2. *Этот кофе для тех, кому важно **качество** и **обжарка** зерен.*

Является ли стилистическим недочётом то, что однородные члены называют далёкие друг от друга характеристики объекта, выраженного общим для этих однородных членов несогласованным определением?

На мой взгляд, да. Необходимо дать однородным членам разные определения.

3. *Для нас важно **количество** участников и их **активность**.*
4. *Этот кофе подходит тем, кому важно **качество** зёрен и их **обжарка**.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это тема правильного составления однородных рядов. Ваш вариант мне представляется **верным,** то есть действительно необходимо дать однородным членам разные определения.

1)  ***Для нас важно количество участников и их активность.***

Мы можем сказать так: Для нас важными являются два фактора: (1) количество участников и (2) их активность. Здесь разные факторы составляют **однородный ряд** по сближенному признаку: они для нас важны.

**Разнородные понятия** (количество и активность) хотя и связаны союзом И, но расположены **на расстоянии друг от друга и входят в разные словосочетания** (каждое имеет свое определение).

Варианты **с другими союзами**: *Для нас важно и количество участников, и их активность. Для нас важно как количество участников, так и их активность.*

2) ***Для нас важно количество и активность участников.***

В этом предложении **разнородные понятия расположены рядом и имеют общее несогласованное определение**, а это является стилистической неточностью.

Некорректность конструкции  **может быть устранена с помощью других союзов,** при которых разнородные понятия разделены (собственная часть двойного союза и интонация). Сравнить:

(1) Для нас важно  количество и активность участников . (2)  Для нас важно и количество,  и активность участников.  Для нас важно как количество,  так и активность участников.

**ВЫВОД**

Объединяя соединительным союзом однородные для данного предложения словосочетания, **мы не должны допускать формального объединения стоящих рядом**  разнородных слов.

Розенталь  http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/67.htm

§208 Ошибки в сочетаниях однородных членов

1. Ошибочным является соединение в нейтральном стиле речи в качестве однородных членов **несопоставимых** (вещественно неоднородных) понятий.

Comment: «Некорректность конструкции ясно видна из примеров с другими союзами: *Для нас важно и количество участников, и активность. Для нас важно как количество участников, так и активность*». Мне не очень понятно, как эти примеры демонтируют некорректность конструкции. Может, лучше так: «и количество, и активность участников»; «как количество, так и активность участников»?

Comment: Посмотрите, я исправила вторую часть ответа.

Comment: А вам не кажется, что изменение вида союза с одиночного «и» на повторяющийся «и …, и...» или на двойной «как…, так и…» данную проблему также не решает? Главная проблема — наличие общего определение для слов, обозначающих разнородные понятия, — остаётся. Всё равно нужны разные определения: "и количество участников, и их активность»; «как количество участников, так и их активность".

Comment: Мне кажется, что решает,  по крайней мере предложение звучит нормально. В стилистике многие проблемы решаются не по смыслу, а по форме. Несочетаемые слова просто не должны стоять рядом.

Comment: Но наша стилистическая проблема же заключалась не в близкой позиции однородных членов по отношению друг к другу, а в их связи с общим несогласованным определением. На мой взгляд, разведение однородных членов не помогает. Да, при прочтении повторяющийся и двойной союзы перетягивают внимание на однородные члены (отчего наша проблема становится чуть менее заметной), но их связь с определением всё равно остаётся и слышится.

Comment: Я уже высказала свое мнение. Если Вы думаете, что разделения слов с помощью союзов недостаточно, то используйте два определения, а не двойные союзы. Это просто разные способы решения задачи о несочетаемости.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90873/discussion-between---and-sharon).

Comment: Честно говоря, я не знаю,что я могу еще добавить.  А у Вас остались  вопросы? (Кстати, система сама может перевести разговор в чат при необходимости).

Comment: А она и переместила. Перейдите по ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему этот недостаток легко разрешается путём постановки сказуемого в форму множественного числа

> 1. Для нас важн**Ы** *(как)* количество *(, так)* и активность участников.
> 2. Этот кофе для тех, кому важн**Ы** *(и)* качество *(,)* и обжарка зерен.

Comment: Интересный выход. Однако он не решает проблему наличия общего определения, относящегося к словам, обозначающим разнородные понятия. К слову сказать, изменение вида союза с одиночного «и» на повторяющийся «и …, и...» или на двойной «как…, так и…» данную проблему также не решает.

Comment: @Василий Ефименко союзы я добавил только потому, что с ними фразы звучат полнее, они необязательны, поясните на примере, что вы имеете в виду под разнородными понятиями

Comment: Слово «количество» обозначает количественную характеристику, «активность» — характеристику деятельности. Поэтому мы говорим, что эти слова обозначают разнородные понятие и их не стоит употреблять с одним определением. Сравнить: «болезненность и размер раны», «яркость и длина лампы». Чувствуете, что не звучит?

Comment: @Василий Ефименко возможно кое-какая дисгармония и присутствует, но по большому счёту лично мне это не мешает, собственно и ответ я дал, исходя из того, что несогласованность по числу - это единственная проблема в ваших примерах

Comment: Это как раз не проблема. У Розенталя есть правило, что если нет необходимости подчёркивать множественность субъектов, выраженных подлежащими, и их раздельную активность, то сказуемое может стоять в единственном числе. Особенно это характерно для сказуемого в препозиции (при нахождении его перед подлежащим), как в нашем случае.

Comment: @Василий Ефименко лично мне режет слух как раз-таки единственное число, значит для меня проблема

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, предложение о кофейных зёрнах минимальными средствами (с сохранением формы) не исправить: "обжарка" больше ассоциируется с *процессом* обжаривания и потому воспринимается как речевая неточность (возникает и вопрос: качество исходных зёрен важно, а важно ли *качество их обжарки*?); "*обжаренность*" или "*факт обжарки*" выглядело бы излишне формально для рекламного стиля. Вариант исправления, в котором подразумевается необходимость именно в *обжаренных* зернах:

> Этот кофе для тех, кому важно качество обжаренных зерен.

Comment: Вы верно подметили, что предложение составлено немного странно. Что означает «важна обжарка»? Следует уточнить: «...кому важно качество зёрен и качество их обжарки / степень их обжарки».

Answer (score 0):

Ваш пример можно отнести к этому правилу.
 Если по смыслу сочетания при единственном числе было бы неясно, связано ли определение с ближайшим существительным или со всем рядом однородных членов, например:

**способные ученик и ученица, построить каменные дом и гараж; полированные шкаф и комод; мелко нарезанные зелень и мясо, талантливо исполненные пьеса для виолончели и концерт для скрипки с оркестром, а также в художественной речи: Зеленели молодые рожь и пшеница (Чехов); И тем большие ответственность и обязанность ложились на нас, наследников чеховской и горьковской славы (Леонов);**

Comment: У нас несогласованное определение. Оно не согласуется в числе с определяемыми словами. Впрочем, у нас определение однозначно относится к обоим однородным членам — проблемы связи определения с ближайшим существительным или со всем рядом однородных членов здесь не стоит. Поэтому указанное вами правило, на мой взгляд, не подходит.

Comment: Серж, я попробую объяснить, почему Ваши примеры сочли неподходящими. Дело в том, что в Ваших примерах два существительных не требуют обязательных определений и могут свободно соединяться союзом И при необходимости, между ними нет противоречия. В заданном примере несогласованное определение является обязательным (по сути это не определение, а необходимое дополнение, как, к примеру,  в счетном обороте "количество участников"). И вот такие существительные (без дополнения)  соединительным союзом связывать в нейтральном стиле не рекомендуется, в том числе просто  формально располагать их рядом